# Apache Axis with Rampart modules giving Deployment Exception

Tags: java, apache-axis, rampart

I am trying to add Apache Rampart Modules to the Apache Axis server. But I am getting following error.

```
[ERROR] The rahas-1.6.2.mar module, which is not valid, caused org.apache.rahas.Rahas
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.rahas.Rahas
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.readModuleArchive(ArchiveReader.java:527)
    ... more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.rahas.Rahas
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleBuilder.loadModuleClass(ModuleBuilder.java:70)
    ... 14 more

[ERROR] The rampart-1.6.2.mar module, which is not valid, caused org.apache.rampart.Rampart
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.rampart.Rampart
    ... more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.rampart.Rampart
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleBuilder.loadModuleClass(ModuleBuilder.java:70)
    ... 14 more
```

I using Apache Axis2 1.6.2 and Apache Rampart 1.6.2. Also tried the [this](http://j2eesolution.blogspot.com/2013/01/configure-axis20.html) but no luck. Any clue on this error?

Comment: Try copying all the jars from the lib folder of Axis2 to the lib folder of your web service application.

Comment: Its not the client app. I am trying to up the Axis2 as service back-end.

Comment: However error occurs because axis cannot find the jar files. What are the files you have in axis.war?

Comment: It is `.mar` files. which resides in `$AXIS2_HOME/repository/modules`. All `.war` files deployed successfully except these modules.

Comment: just sought out the problem. You need copy all the libraries in the lib directory of Rampart binary distribution to Axis2 lib directory. Not only `.mar` files.

Comment: Add it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer and posting here hoping someone will find this useful.

According to the rampart quick start guide in [here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/quick-start.html); You need to follow two steps;

1. Copy all the module files to in the modules directory of Rampart binary
   distribution to Axis2 modules
   directory($AXIS_HOME/repository/modules/)
2. Copy all the libraries in the lib directory of Rampart
   binary distribution to Axis2 lib directory($AXIS2_HOME/lib).

In my case; I missed the step 2. Thus, on the error stack in the deep it showing  `Deployment Exception` is caused by the `ClassNotFound Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Download the Axis jar axis2-1.7.4.jar , import into eclipse using the import existing from File or Folder structure.
Then copy the rampart-1.7.1.mar and rahas-1.7.1.mar (which was downloaded separately from google) into WEB-INF/module folder.
Then ant build.xml change the type of file to jar and ran the script to create axis new jar.
Add the jar to project class path where you want to deploy rampart with axis.